# What is the meaning of using it this way in overloaded function?

Tags: c++

I came across following code in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const std::vector<T>& v) {
    // This line writes an opening curly brace { to the output stream s.
    s.put('{');
    for (char comma[]{'\0', ' ', '\0'}; const auto& e : v)
        s << comma << e, comma[0] = ','; // <== This line
    return s << "}\n";
}
```

I don't really understand the following block of code in the above function:

```
    for (char comma[]{'\0', ' ', '\0'}; const auto& e : v)
        s << comma << e, comma[0] = ',';  // <== This line
```

Can somebody explain it?

```
// Below line defines a char array. I got it.
char comma[]{'\0', ' ', '\0'};
```

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do?

Comment: Really beats me why cppreference uses this code-golfe-esque style in their examples. I came trying to understand something, not to distangle some overly terse snippet, ffs.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It shouldn't be this easy to close a question. Can you tell me which answer in the link you gave me should I look at to understand my question?

Comment: `s << comma << e, comma[0] = ',';` is just a slightly shorter, less readable way of writing `{s << comma << e; comma[0] = ',';}`

Comment: @QweQwe  I'm *not* the one closing the answer, I'm just providing a reference that might be a duplicate.

Comment: For better understanding, run the snippet and change the initial value of `comma[]`. See what happens. Keep in mind `\0`s special function.

Comment: @nick with the help of the answer and alan's comment, i figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (char comma[]{'\0', ' ', '\0'}; const auto& e : v)
        s << comma << e, comma[0] = ',';
```

`comma` is "\0 " at the first loop iteration.

`s << comma << e` dumps the empty zero-terminated C string and `e`.

`comma[0] = ','` after that modifies `comma` to contain ", ".

Further iteration dump ", " and then `e`.